# Linux Kernel List, Freeing memory

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am currently learning some Linux Driver writing, and i try to implement list with the Linux Kernel list API.

My code just allocate a list and add 2 elements to it.
All go Ok until i try to free the memory i allocate, here i got a segmentation fault, and from what i test, it come from list_del call.
But i cannot see where i did wrong.

Here is my code :

```
struct drv_cdev{
    int devno;
};

struct drv_dev_itf {
    struct drv_cdev cdev; //DATA
    struct list_head cdev_list;
};

struct drv_dev {
    int number;
    struct list_head list_master;
    struct drv_dev_itf drv_dev_itf;
};

void add_node(struct drv_dev *dev, int num)
{
    struct drv_dev_itf *new_cdev;

    new_cdev = kmalloc(sizeof(struct drv_dev_itf*), GFP_KERNEL);

    new_cdev->cdev.devno = num;

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&new_cdev->cdev_list);
    list_add(&new_cdev->cdev_list, &dev->list_master);
}

void destroy_list(struct drv_dev *dev)
{
    struct list_head *position;
    struct drv_dev_itf *data_structure;

    list_for_each (position, &dev->list_master) {
    data_structure = list_entry(position, struct drv_dev_itf, cdev_list);
    printk("Devno testing : %d\n", data_structure->cdev.devno);
    //dev_node_release(driver_class, &data_structure->cdev);

    list_del(position);
    printk("List head deleted\n");
    /*kfree(data_structure);
    printk("List data_structure deleted\n");*/
    }
 }

static int __init test_init(void)
{
    struct drv_dev *dev;

    dev = kmalloc(sizeof(*dev), GFP_KERNEL);

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&dev->list_master);
    add_node(dev, 1);
    add_node(dev, 2);
    destroy_list(dev);

    kfree(dev);
    return 0;

}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers, have a nice day.

Comment: If you're removing the elements from within list_for_each, the header file says you should use list_for_each_safe

Comment: Ok i will try this thanks you

Comment: @user253751 Thank you it work perfectly, have a nice day